How to use matrices as vertex labeling in graph?
I have some 2*2 matrices, which I want to use as vertex labels in graph. so how to do it?

Any expression can be used as a label, and it will display in the same way as in the notebook.

For an example, take e.g.:
gr = GraphData["ButterflyGraph"]


To add labels of 2x2 matrices, we use e.g. "MatrixForm" like:
Graph[gr, 
 VertexLabels -> 
  Table[MatrixForm@RandomInteger[{0, 9}, {2, 2}], {i, 5}]]



Thank you, Daniel Huber

but I want a specific label to a specific vertex. How to do that ?

Make a list with your labels. And then use VertexLabels-> yourList
